# div in bottom of window, not page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a div element, in a bottom of window. like a div in bottom page of old facebook.com. or like a chat div of initial facebook.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed; bottom: 0px`. But won't work in IE6.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; }
</style>

<div id="footer">I am at the bottom of the window</div>
```

Comment: There are also few workarounds for IE6 support. Try searching for ie-fixed.htc - the .htc file will force IE to understand the position.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.  The bottom bar here is made with a div element.  I would imagine you can use any element you wish, just reference the CSS class.  I have only tested the div element

```
/* HTML */
<div class='always-at-bottom'>Always at bottom!</div>

/* CSS */
.always-at-bottom {
    height:40px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```