# Put a div on bottom of the screen, not page

Tags: html, css, alignment, progress-bar

I am trying to put a gray bar on the bottom of the screen of my webpage, regardless of the resolution. However, when I try, it seems to just go up or down when I go in a different resolution. Is there any way to fix this?

Also, the bar is made out of CSS using the `div` id tag.

```
/* HTML*/
<div id="info">Scroll for info</div>

/* CSS */
<style>
#info { 
    height: 40px; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: 25%; 
    background-color: #393838; 
    opacity: 
}
</style>
```

**EDIT:** I want it to be on the bottom of the screen, but then when I scroll down it goes up towards the top of my screen.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A query for `Put a div on bottom of the screen, not page` will give you the correct answer (e.g. [div in bottom of window, not page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371588)

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: CSS: #info {
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
    margin-top: 25%;
 background-color: #393838;
 opacity:
}

Comment: HTML: <div id="info">Scroll for info</div>

Comment: You know your CSS is invalid?

Answer (score 90):

If you want it on the bottom and always at the bottom, you have to use `position: fixed`. 
You could try this:

```
#info { 
    height: 40px; 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:0%;
    width:100%; 
    background-color: #393838; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rX4nd/1/

Comment: By defualt it is at the left. You can set right: 0%

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Documentation that should help you with what you want.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom

Tl;dr, set "position: fixed" to place it at the bottom of the rendered part of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding entering as well?

```
.someDiv {
  position:fixed;
  width:50%;
  height:300px;
  margin-left:-25%;
  background:#063;
  bottom:0px;
  left:50%;
}
```