# Div with position: fixed inside a jQuery UI Dialog Box doesn't float to the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371588/div-in-bottom-of-window-not-page), I should be able to do something like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">
  This is a test
</div>
```

and have it float to the bottom of the screen.

I tried entering just that snippet in JSFiddle and it worked exactly how I expected it to - the text floated to the bottom.

Next, I tried the following in JSFiddle:

```
<div id="test">
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">
    This is a test
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="$('#test').dialog({ title: 'Test' })"/>
```

This had the following outcome:

[image]

This still isn't really what I want because it's at the bottom of the screen rather than the bottom of the jQuery dialog, but it's closer.

However, when I do the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="historyRepeater" />
        </Triggers>

        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="myDialog" style="display: none">
                <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">
                    This is a test
                </div>
                <!-- Rest of dialog... -->
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

It doesn't float to the bottom at all - it just stays "in place" on the dialog. It appears to completely ignore the CSS properties.

How do I get the text to float to the bottom of the dialog (rather than the window)? I'm trying to get the text to stay at the bottom of the dialog when I scroll. And why does the browser seem to completely ignore the CSS?

I'm testing this in IE11 in Compatibility Mode for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Position fixed will position an element relative to the *viewport*. Position absolute will position an element relative to its *closest non-static positioned ancestor.*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="test" style="position: relative; display: none;">
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
    This is a test
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="$('#test').dialog({ title: 'Test' })"/>
```